# Safe item removal by index from changing array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets say items are frequently added via push into an array. Another async function(which runs independently in a setInterval context) removes random items from the array.

In this second function, when in one line I evaluate the index of the item to be removed, the array could change before I reach the next line where I do array.splice(index, 1). Correct? The wrong item would be removed.

How should I solve that?

EDIT: example:

```
async function analyze() {

  let pendingTxs = [] 

  web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', function(error, result){
    if (error) console.log(error);
  })
  .on("data", async function(hash){   
    pendingTxs.push(hash)    
  })  

  setInterval(async () => {    
    
    let promises = pendingTxs.map(pTx => {return web3.eth.getTransaction(pTx)})

    let updatedTransactions = await Promise.all(promises)

    for (let index = 0; index < updatedTransactions.length; index++) {
      const txUpdated = updatedTransactions[index];
      if (txUpdated.transactionIndex != null) {
        const index = pendingTxs.indexOf(txUpdated.hash)
        if (index > -1) {          
          pendingTxs.splice(index, 1);          
        }
      }
    }

  },250)
  
}

analyze()
```

EDIT2: I think Chris may be right in this case.

Comment: You should add a [mcve] to your question to better illustrate the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Can't you evaluate the item instead (using `.find()`) then remove it using `.filter()`? However .push() puts the item at the very end, so it shouldn't be an issue in the first place. Even if a new item is pushed, the index of the randomly selected one won't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

```
const index = pendingTxs.indexOf(txUpdated.hash)
if (index > -1) {          
  pendingTxs.splice(index, 1);          
}
```

runs as a unit.

JavaScript's `async` functions are cooperative, not preemptive.

["Difference between Preemptive and Cooperative Multitasking"](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-preemptive-and-cooperative-multitasking/#:%7E:text=Preemptive%20multitasking%20is%20a%20task,running%20process%20to%20another%20process.)

> In *cooperative multitasking*, the [controller] never initiates context switching from the running [thread] to another [thread]. A context switch occurs only when the [thread] voluntarily yields control

since JS is based on [event loop concurrency](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop)

So if you do an `await` or `yield`, then other code may run, but if you do not explicitly do one of those pausing actions, then the instructions above run as a unit.

[*SharedArrayBuffer*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer)s are an exception to this because the host is allowed to share their contents widely, but *Array*s are not so shared.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I was not sure because another async function where I first update a value in a sqlite db and then read it caused concurrency issues. I had to solve that with a mutex. Those db calls were awaits.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like you've got a transactional invariant involving an external system with its own concurrency.   A mutex might make sure that two operations hitting it from the same JS engine don't cause problems but if there are multiple engines, you might want to try https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html